# SQL set variable to a value in the current row

Tags: sql, t-sql

What I am trying to do is perform a loop that goes through each column in my table and sets the variable @agent to that column's agentID.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    Declare @index int = 1
    Declare @agentCount = Max(rowID)
    Declare @agentID int

    While(@i =< @agentCount)
    Begin
         If(@index = rowID)
         Begin
                 --Set @agentID (to current row's agentID)
                 Exec mergeagentLogRecords @agentID, @startDate, @endDate
         End
    Set @index = @index + 1
    End
```

I hope I explained myself well enough :P
Thanks for looking!

Comment: Each column or each row? What is the table structure and what is the definition of `mergeagentLogRecords`? Row by row processing should be avoided in favour of set based processing where possible.

Comment: Where is it that you retrieve the contents of your table? What is the structure of your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this, depending on how you're generating rowID:

```
SELECT @agentID = agentID FROM agentTable WHERE @index = rowID;
```

And then continue on your merry way with whatever it is your logic needs to do.

Comment: How could I pass the @agentID into my stored procedure with this method?

Comment: @AaronJohnsen, the way you are doing it in your code already. The `SELECT` statement will store the agentID into the `@agentID` variable. You'll then use the variable in your stored proc (as you've already shown) and its value will be used in the parameter.